# Is there a word that means "impressionable," but from the point of view of the impresser?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

For instance, something that easily puts an impression on others. Note this is slightly different from "impressive," though that word also fits the meaning.

Comment: ***How*** is this word different from *impressive*? That means "creates an impression in others" -- or in me; but others are definitely in scope. Why do you reject it?

Comment: I have to agree with @AndrewLeach. The rejection of *impressive* makes no sense as it's clearly the word the first sentence requests. If people knew why it was rejected, it would help them provide much better answers.

Comment: Consider “He's a very impressionable child”. Now consider the person (say, his teacher) who takes advantage of this to mould the child’s opinions by instilling impressions. “He's a very impressive teacher” is not very apt as a description of the teacher, if you ask me. _Impressionable_ is overwhelmingly negative, while _impressive_ is overwhelmingly positive; they don't really form as much of a pair as their derivations would have you believe.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this simply **persuasive**?

From the dictionary Google supplies:

> persuasive       adjective
>
> good at persuading someone to do or believe something through
>   reasoning or the use of temptation.
>
> synonyms: convincing, effective, cogent, compelling, potent, forceful,
>   eloquent, impressive, weighty, influential, sound, valid, powerful,
>   strong, effectual, efficacious, winning, telling, plausible, credible
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

If someone is impressionable they're open to manipulation, so [manipulative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/manipulative) might be an option.

Note that unlike persuasive, as already suggested, manipulative has negative connotations. However, I think this is apt, as being impressionable isn't usually a positive trait either: it implies one is easily led astray.

Answer (score 0):

If I look at someone and say they are impressive or persuasive, then in that scenario, I am the "impressee", not the "impresser".

From the point of view of the impresser would mean that the other person is easily impressed. *Gullible* or *naive* fit loosely here. Off the top of my head, I can't think of a word with a positive connotation. Even "child-like" can be bad.

If you're actually looking for a synonym for *impressive*, I'm sure the thesaurus could help. The first word that springs to mind when describing something that has "left an impression on me" is *memorable* (or *unforgettable*).

Answer (score 0):

.... *matter of opinion*

**[imposing](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/imposing)**, adj., used of a person's appearance or behavior.

- “the monarch's imposing presence”

**[dignified](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/dignified)**,adj., dignified means self-respecting and worthy,especially formality or stateliness in bearing or appearance.

- “her dignified demeanor”

*Reference- vocabulary.com*